# Trouble binding nested collections

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, nested

I'm a beginner at WPF, and I'm trying to bind a nested collection.

I've found many topics online about binding, and I tried following [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924658/datatemplating-for-data-binding-of-nested-observablecollections). I tried changing the Datacontext and ItemSource values, but I just can't seem to get it right.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Nav1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="620" d:DesignWidth="950">
<Grid Background="#FF741125">
    <TextBlock Height="61" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="BEVERAGES" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Black" />
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Stack" DataContext="{Binding myMenu}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Subs}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,60,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,60,0,0">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="60" Width="900">
                                    <Grid.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/MenuGrid.fw.png" />
                                    </Grid.Background>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Cost}" ContentStringFormat="{}${0}" Grid.Column="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                                </Grid>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

Class:

```
public class Menu
{
    public ObservableCollection<Category> Subs;

    public Menu()
    {
        Subs = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Nodes;
    public Category()
    {
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    }
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }
    public Category(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
    }

    public MenuItem(string name, string description, double cost)
    {
        this.itemName = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    private string itemName;
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return this.itemName; }
        set { this.itemName = value; }
    }

    private string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return this.description; }
        set { this.description = value; }
    }

    private double cost;
    public double Cost
    {
        get { return this.cost; }
        set { this.cost = value; }
    }
}
```

CS:

```
public Nav1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Init Model
        Menu myMenu = new Menu();
        myMenu.Subs.Add(new Category("Soft Drinks"));
        myMenu.Subs.Add(new Category("Coffee"));
        myMenu.Subs.Add(new Category("Premium"));

        myMenu.Subs[0].Nodes.Add(new MenuItem("Pepsi", "Cool & Refreshing", 1.39));
        myMenu.Subs[0].Nodes.Add(new MenuItem("Diet Pepsi", "Cool & Refreshing", 1.39));
        myMenu.Subs[0].Nodes.Add(new MenuItem("7Up", "Cool & Refreshing", 1.39));
        myMenu.Subs[0].Nodes.Add(new MenuItem("Mug Root Beer", "Cool & Refreshing", 1.39));
        myMenu.Subs[0].Nodes.Add(new MenuItem("Brisk Iced Tea", "Cool & Refreshing", 1.39));
        myMenu.Subs[0].Nodes.Add(new MenuItem("Bottled Water", "Thirsty? Aquafina.", 2.75));
        // Set DataContext for StackPanel
        Stack.DataContext = myMenu.Subs;
    }
```

It displays the category names (eg. "Soft Drinks" or "Coffee") but I can't display the individual items. Also, are there better ways to do this? As mentioned, I'm a beginner at WPF and there seem to be many interesting functions I'm missing.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You need to use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead of a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Hi @Bob, that got me in the right direction! I switched to using `TreeView` + `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, following [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx).

If you could add your comment as an answer, I would like to mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not allow for the using of nested items since it does not provide an `ItemsSource` property.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text={Binding MyTextValue}/>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, if you use a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to define the next level of items.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource={Binding MyListOfLevelTwoItems}>
    <TextBlock Text={Binding MyLevelOneValue}/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type MyLevelTwoItem}>
    <TextBlock Text={Binding MyLevelTwoValue}/>
</DataTemplate>
```